# Thymeleaf unable to find template folder with error : class path resource [templates/error] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

While trying to load the swagger ui im getting the following error from the application:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/error] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

the dependency im using :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

this is happening after the spring boot version was updated, the previous version didnt show this issue.

Also my

> src/main/resources/templates

folder did not have any error folder before the upgrade as well.

Would appreciate if anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: where have you put your thymleaf file

Comment: Post your full error... I doubt it is an actual error but rather an INFO or WARNING indicating that it tries to find an `error.html` but doesn't find it (and this is the warning that gets log).

Comment: Update! After adding the error.html file in the src->main->resources->templates->error folder the exception is gone. But now the swagger doesnt load and the error.html page loads by default. i have no stacktrace for the same in the console log as no error is printed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put html/thymeleaf files inside
`src->main->resources->templates-> YOUR_HTML files`

also check in your pom.xml, that thymleaf has been added

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```